# RxJava - SwitchMap alike with multiple limited active streams

Tags: concurrency, rx-java

I'm wondering how to transform an observable similarly to switchMap but instead of limiting to single active stream have multiple (limited) streams.

The purpose is to have multiple tasks working concurrently up to some tasks count limit, and allow new tasks to start with FIFO queue strategy, meaning any new task arrive will start immediately and the oldest task in queue will be canceled.

switchMap will create Observable for each emission of the source and will cancel previous running Observable stream once new one created, I want to achieve something similar but allow concurrency with some level (like flatMap), meaning allowing number of Observables to be created for each emission, and run concurrently up to some concurrency limit, when the concurrency limit is reached, the oldest observable will be cancel and the new one will started.

Actually, This is also similar to flatMap with maxConcurrent, but instead of new Observables waiting in queue when maxConcurrent is reached, cancel the older Observables and enter the new one immediately.

Comment: I don't believe that such an operator exists in rxJava (or any RX implementation I'm familiar with). If you have a good use case for it you can go ahead and submit a feature request [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues).

Comment: mmm, thought so, I will try to come up with something myself, and share it to see if I'm in the right direction

Comment: Is this for rxjava 1 or 2?

Comment: it is for rxjava 1, already looked at rxjava-extras Dave, maybe I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with this transformer:

```
public static <T, R> Observable.Transformer<T, R> switchFlatMap(
        int n, Func1<T, Observable<R>> mapper) {
    return f -> 
        Observable.defer(() -> {
            final AtomicInteger ingress = new AtomicInteger();
            final Subject<Integer, Integer> cancel = 
                    PublishSubject.<Integer>create().toSerialized();

            return f.flatMap(v -> {
                int id = ingress.getAndIncrement();
                Observable<R> o = mapper.call(v)
                        .takeUntil(cancel.filter(e -> e == id + n));
                cancel.onNext(id);
                return o;
            });
        })
    ;
}
```

The demonstration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PublishSubject<Integer> ps = PublishSubject.create();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    PublishSubject<Integer>[] pss = new PublishSubject[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < pss.length; i++) {
        pss[i] = PublishSubject.create();
    }

    AssertableSubscriber<Integer> ts = ps
    .compose(switchFlatMap(2, v -> pss[v]))
    .test();

    ps.onNext(0);
    ps.onNext(1);

    pss[0].onNext(1);
    pss[0].onNext(2);
    pss[0].onNext(3);

    pss[1].onNext(10);
    pss[1].onNext(11);
    pss[1].onNext(12);

    ps.onNext(2);

    pss[0].onNext(4);

    pss[2].onNext(20);
    pss[2].onNext(21);
    pss[2].onNext(22);

    pss[1].onCompleted();
    pss[2].onCompleted();
    ps.onCompleted();

    ts.assertResult(1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22);
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's my direction, actually I've tried something like that, the one problem with this approach is that takeUntil will not unsubscribe from the source Observable, but just will cut its emissions, so we'll have new Observable that ignore these emissions. 
I want the source to be unsubscribed (like in switchMap) as I want the resources to be freed (my case to cancel a network request)

Comment: `takeUntil` does unsubscribe from the inner sources, why do you think otherwise?

Comment: very elegant, love it!

Comment: thanks akarnokd for you solution!!
Actually I've try already something with takeUntil, and got confuse as I expected to get terminal events, thus mistakenly make this conclusion.
anyhow now I can back off from my much more complicated solution of wrapping the observable and get back to the takeUntil method, also your code is much more elegant than what I came out with, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Though a ready made solution is unavailable, something like below should assist.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Observable.create(subscriber -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toBlocking().subscribe();
                    subscriber.onNext(i);
                }
            })
            .switchMap(
                    n -> {
                        System.out.println("Main task emitted event - " + n);
                        return Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).take((int) n * 3)
                                .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> System.out.println("Unsubscribed for main task event - "+ n));
                    }).subscribe(n2 -> System.out.println("\t" + n2));

    Observable.timer(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toBlocking().subscribe();
}
```

`Observable.create` section creates a slow producer which emits items in a fashion of emit 0, sleep for 1s and emit 1, sleep for 2s and emit 2 and so on.

`switchMap` creates `Observable` objects for each element which emits numbers every second. You also can note that it prints a line every time an element is emitted by the main `Observable` and also when it is unsubscribed.

Thus, probably in your case, you might be interested to close the oldest task with `doOnUnsubscribe`. Hope it helps.

Below pseudo code might help better in understanding.

```
getTaskObservable()
        .switchMap(
                task -> {
                    System.out.println("Main task emitted event - " + task);
                    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
                        initiateTaskAndNotify(task, subscriber);
                    }).doOnUnsubscribe(() -> checkAndKillIfMaxConcurrentTasksReached(task));
                }).subscribe(value -> System.out.println("Done with task and got output" + value));
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand how that answer my requirements?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a pseudo code to help understand better. Please check and let me know.

Comment: it's not answer my requirements as your'e doing switchMap, that will kill (unsubscribe) last subscriber for each new emission, moreover, the event for which I need to unsubscribe the oldest Observable is subscribe not unsubscribe. see my detailed description in the question.
you can check akarnokd answer code to understand the difference, thanks.